# Filter predicate that filters all items after it's encountered a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter, array-filter

Below I have an array filter predicate that will remove all items when it encounters a number, including the number. I'm worried about the performance of this predicate as it runs the entire filter many more times then it needs to (forgive me I don't know the bigO). This is because if I want the global state of when it's encountered the number within the predicate I have to access the third argument which is the entire array.

Is there another way to do this, and still have a predicate with no variables outside the predicate scope?

```
const filterNumberOrAfter = (_: any, index: number, array: any[]): boolean => {
  let encounterdNumber = false
  const total = array.filter((path) => {
    if (encounterdNumber) return false
    if (typeof path === 'number') {
      encounterdNumber = true
      return false
    }
    return true
  })
  return Boolean(total[index])
}

console.log(['hello', 'world', 'meow', 2, 'example', 'rest'].filter(filterNumberOrAfter))
// [ "hello", "world", "meow" ]
```

Comment: Will there always be no more than one number in the array? (If there may be more, then you must iterate over the entire array to remove them)

Comment: @CertainPerformance may have no, 1, or many numbers

Comment: What is the expected outcome when there are multiple numbers? looks like a slice combined with findIndex is all you need.

Comment: @pilchard I'm asking specifically is there a way to do this only using array methods and predicates, no other outside variables

Comment: both slice and findIndex are array methods.

Comment: Sure you *can* - that's what you're doing at the moment. But it's clunky. Better to use a more appropriate approach.

Comment: well first of all, you can't break the filter method which means it runs through the whole array regardless. second, you run it again inside the first filter so total runs will be n*n. which is a lot. instead use a for .. of or a classic fo loop and splice the array. as for scope, use functions?

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize is by encapsulating the predicate within a function and caching the initial run of the filter in the parent scope that way each iteration of the filter has access to the original filtered array that only ran once.

```
const filterNumberOrAfter = () => {
  let total: string[] = []
  return (_: any, index: number, array: any[]): boolean => {
    if (index === 0) {
      let encounterdNumber = false
      total = array.filter((path) => {
        if (encounterdNumber) return false
        if (typeof path === 'number') {
          encounterdNumber = true
          return false
        }
        return true
      })
    }
    return Boolean(total[index])
  }
}

console.log(['hello', 'world', 'meow', 2, 'example', 'rest'].filter(filterNumberOrAfter()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The the commenters credit, this is a nice oneliner that is much easier to read.

```
const getItemsTillNumber = (arr: any[]) => {
  const i = arr.findIndex((item) => typeof item === 'number')
  return arr.slice(0, i === -1 ? arr.length : i)
}
```

Comment: keep in mind that `findIndex()` returns `-1` when no match is found, so as written you will remove the last element of the array in that case, and keep the whole array when the first element is a number.